# Is there any specific order to the four Elements when people talk about them?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore

In Dungeons and Dragons, the four elements are Air, Earth, Fire, and Water (like the planes and the elementals). In the lore, is there any specific order to these elements, for example the order people might use in casual conversation when discussing them? Or is the order just usually alphabetical and has no lore? For example, in Avatar: the Last Airbender, people might talk about the elements in the order of the Avatar cycle (water, earth, fire, air; starting at any arbitrary element), although people might do that differently (or not at all) in D&D worlds.

Comment: I feel that "any setting ever used with D&D" is a tad broad. You should focus on one setting: the one you are using in your game.

Comment: Is there a problem that arises from the dis/order of the elements you are attempting to resolve? Or some specific related piece of lore that deals with the elements and whose interaction causes the order to matter (like your example of the Avatar cycle)?

Comment: @Rykara  I was going to have homebrewed golems based on the four elements and their Mk. number would be 1-4 or I-IV. I wanted to see if there was an official order so i could number them correctly, however, it looks like there isn't so i will make up my own order.

Comment: @Szega I understand where you are coming from, however this is rather a lore question than a ruling questions. To my understanding, while the mechanics have changed, the world in which dnd takes place is still basically the same. I wouldn't want to miss out on lore from any of the other editions, so that's why I have it for all Dungeons and Dragons

Comment: Clearly, it's "Earth, Wind, and Fire, (oh yeah, I guess water, too)"

Comment: @Deus Re Szega's comment, setting is not the same as edition. You are right that settings often persist across editions. But there are still multiple settings which you can play D&D in. For example: Forgotten Realms, Eberron, Greyhawk, Dragonlance. Each may have a different cosmology or view of the elements (although there is often overlap between settings).

Comment: Plato believed each element was a platonic solid. In ascending order, they would go fire (d4), earth (d6), air (d8), water (d12), with the d20 representing the universe as a whole. If you're looking for an arbitrary order to use, why not this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There's no official order for the elements in D&D.

I'm assuming that, in the typical D&D setting, a person knowledgeable of the planes and the cosmology might use the order in which the four Elemental Planes appear, either clockwise (Air, Fire, Earth, Water), or anticlockwise (the opposite), with any element as a starting point.  This however might be a personal preference of certain individuals / scholars, and is certainly not a rule in the lore.

Reference: in 5e, there's a map of the planes at page 303, PHB.
The elemental planes show opposed air/earth and opposed fire/water as far back as the AD&D 1e PHB (p. page 121).
[image]
(Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, Players Handbook, Gary Gygax, TSR, 1978; p. 121)
And this is the current PHB diagram(Appendix C)
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason for starting with Air and not, for example, with Water?

Comment: @Eddymage That's entirely personal preference, or alphabetic first if you want. An individual could even call the planes air, earth, fire, water just because of starting letter for instance.